# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installation error on ASUS Zenbook Pro UX550VD

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on ASUS Zenbook Pro UX550VD to dual boot it with Windows 10, but everytime I would boot up Ubuntu from USB stick one of these happen:

1. Ubuntu loading screen stops and computer shuts down.
2. Ubuntu loads for some time, error messages get thrown out and computer shuts down.
3. Error messages are thrown and computer shuts down.

Error messages:
[image: Error message]

I have tried writing `pci=nomsi` in GRUB parameters and I could boot Ubuntu for a while, but issues still persisted.

BIOS is up-to-date. (Version 307)

Any help is appreciated.